# Get email from external login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, facebook-login, account

My colleague have made our site that we can log in using external login. They way it works is that the code checks if the username from external site exist in Mvc Entityframeworks UserProfile table in the database, if it doesnt exist it will create a new user. What we want to do is only to bind the external to a user in the databse and not to create a new user. And we decided to use the email to bind, so the program will check if the external email exist in email column that is related to userid.

If the external email exist in the database you can log in with this account and get the correct priviliges that this userid have.

My question is how can i get the email from external with a simple code and maybe even put it in a property so i can compare with the emails in database